# Wordpress Image uploads plugin needed

Tags: plugins

I am looking for a wordpress plugin where I can upload images and store them into a category.

For example I would have say..10 images to upload, I would give the album a name or date and then upload them.

Is there any plugins around that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like NextGen Gallery would be a good fit - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Answer (score 2):

I use WP-Filebase and it's pretty good. Not just images but virtually any type of attachment. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filebase/